# html <textarea> не выводит весь текст

Tags: php, html, html5, textarea

Из дб берётся текст, записывается в переменную.
Переменная выводится через `php` на страницу в `<textarea>`

```
echo("<textarea> $text </textarea>");
```

Текст очень большой, `<textarea>` его обрезает и не выводит полностью.
В чем проблема?

Чем выводить подобные тексты? С быстрой возможностью выделения как в `<textarea>`.

Comment: Что за магия такая "быстрая возможность выделения"? Что нужно от текста? редактировать его? Только просматривать\выделять\копировать?

Comment: Выделить, скопировать, отредактировать прямо в окне. Быстрая возможность выделения это ctrl+A

Comment: А что значит обрезает? текст есть , только его не видно? если так то css

Comment: Размер текста "большой" это сколько? только что проверил 15мб текста - успешно отобразилось. и если возможно пример текста который не отображается, например на пастбин

Answer (score 0):

```
<textarea maxlength="10000"></textarea>
```

пробуйте так, возможно php не причем, тем более неизвестно как формируется  ***$text;***